# NewRelic conflict with parse object

Tags: android, newrelic

I have recently integrated newRelic with my android app, but as soon as i add jar file of new Relic my parse object gives me Fatal Error.

```
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): java.lang.VerifyError: com/parse/ParseACL
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:2764)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:160)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.codenterprise.CashbackKorting.Tab.onCreate(Tab.java:111)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
03-21 15:17:34.739: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting this error while executing this line

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("My");
```

If i removes jar file for newRelic then it runs perfect.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: after adding .jar file clean and built your project

Comment: @ Simple Plan I Worked on your suggestion but it didn't worked.

Comment: now update your New Relic tools and try.

Comment: @ Simple Plan i already have the latest version.

Comment: I've got the same issue. What lines do you see above the exception? I see: `04-01 14:27:33.164: W/dalvikvm(14538): VFY: attempt to access field via uninitialized ref
04-01 14:27:33.164: W/dalvikvm(14538): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x5b at 0x0015
04-01 14:27:33.164: W/dalvikvm(14538): VFY:  rejected Lcom/parse/ParseACL;.copy ()Lcom/parse/ParseACL;
04-01 14:27:33.164: W/dalvikvm(14538): Verifier rejected class Lcom/parse/ParseACL;
`